# Sending images in Mandrill

Tags: node.js, express, qr-code, mailchimp, mandrill

Trying to send QR codes via email with mandrill. Here's what I've got so far:

```
db.get(id, function (err, doc) {
  if (err) { fail('Couch', [err, doc]) }
  db.attachment.get(id, 'qr-code.png', function (error, image) {
    // Base64 encode the image.
    var base64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' + new Buffer(image).toString('base64');
```

Up to this point, I'm good. `base64` can be used in an html img tag to render the qr code, woohoo! The bit I'm having trouble with is next...

```
    // Email Tickets to client
    mandrill('/messages/send-template', {
      template_name: 'qr-confirm',
      template_content: [],
```

`template_content` is supposed to be empty if I'm just using merge_vars right?

```
      message: {
        to: [{email: doc.email, name: doc.name}],
        from_email: 'events@example.com',
        from_name: 'The Team',
        subject: "QR codes attached",
        tags: ['qr'],
        merge_vars: [{
          rcpt: doc.email,
          vars: [
            { name: "name", content: doc.name },
            { name: "attendee", content: doc.id },
            { name: "purchaser", content: doc.purchaser }
          ]
        }],
```

Okay, do I need both `attachments` and `images` or if I use images will it automatically attach them?

```
        attachments: [
          {type: "image/png", name: "qr-code.png", content: base64}
        ],
        images: [
          {type: "image/png", name: "qr-code.png", content: base64}
        ],
      }
    }, function(error, manReply) { console.log(error || manReply) }); // manReply, haha 
  });
});
```

Okay, so with all that, I still get a broken attachment. There's an attachment, it's just broken 1kb, and not rendering inline either.

Any help would rock!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, problem solved, just don't include `data:image/png;base64,` in the content parameter : )